# Passing scan result to other intent

Tags: java, android, zxing

I got the scan result from scan fragment but how am I able to send the result to other intent?

**In My Scan Fragment**

```html
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Trial.class);
            intent1.putExtra("Barcodes", "hi");
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure on your question here. You can send the data back to your calling activity? Does the code above not work? Do you not know how to retrieve the data from the new activity?

Comment: I know how to call Intent to call other activity. But now I have a scan fragment which i can perform the scan action. Once I scan the QR code, i will have the content. How am I able to send the content from fragment to other activity?

Comment: Ok, but just to be clear here: Do you want to send the data from the fragment to its parent activity or from the fragment to a new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** [IntentResult](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java) is a final class and do not implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) interface, so you cannot send it to another activity by using `Intent.putExtra()`.

**Solution:** Create your own ScanResult class which is a clone version of IntentResult.

*ScanResult.java*

```
public class ScanResult implements Parcelable {

    public String contents;
    public String formatName;
    public byte[] rawBytes;
    public Integer orientation;
    public String errorCorrectionLevel;

    public ScanResult(IntentResult intentResult) {
        contents = intentResult.getContents();
        formatName = intentResult.getFormatName();
        rawBytes = intentResult.getRawBytes();
        orientation = intentResult.getOrientation();
        errorCorrectionLevel = intentResult.getErrorCorrectionLevel();
    }

    protected ScanResult(Parcel in) {
        contents = in.readString();
        formatName = in.readString();
        rawBytes = in.createByteArray();
        long orientationInLong = in.readLong();
        orientation = orientationInLong != Long.MAX_VALUE ? (int) orientationInLong : null;
        errorCorrectionLevel = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(contents);
        dest.writeString(formatName);
        dest.writeByteArray(rawBytes);
        dest.writeLong(orientation != null ? orientation : Long.MAX_VALUE);
        dest.writeString(errorCorrectionLevel);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<ScanResult> CREATOR = new Creator<ScanResult>() {
        @Override
        public ScanResult createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ScanResult(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ScanResult[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ScanResult[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Using it in your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        ScanResult scanResult = new ScanResult(result);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Trial.class);
        intent1.putExtra("scanResult", scanResult);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```

In received activity (Trial.java)

```
ScanResult scanResult = getIntent().getParcelableExtra<ScanResult>("scanResult");
```